# Create textboxs dynamically and shift focus to next texbox on click of "Enter" key in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an exe file

1. Which creates dynamic textboxes(no. of textboxes depends upon the user input in the one already provided textbox),
2. In the beginning it focus on the 1st textbox,
3. It should move focus to next textbox on click of "ENTER" key.

**What I'm trying is:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtbx;
        txtbx = new TextBox();
        txtbx.Location = new Point(10, a);
        a += 30;
        this.Controls.Add(txtbx);
        if(i==1)
        {
            txtbx.Focus();
        }
    }
}

public void Form1_KeyPessed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ENTER)
    {

            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use for loop, find your active textbox, then get the next (i+1) textbox and call .Focus()

Comment: Use `SelectNextControl` method instead of `Send`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use  <kbd>[Control.TabIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx)</kbd>  Property and you need to bind key down event for each newly created Text box

**Try this :**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtbx;
            txtbx = new TextBox();
            txtbx.Location = new Point(10, a);
            txtbx.KeyDown += Txtbx_KeyDown; //Added
            txtbx.TabIndex = i;  //Added
            a += 30;
            this.Controls.Add(txtbx);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                txtbx.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now add Key down handler

```
//Added
private void Txtbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
}
```